# Inserting code before assigning a form into an entity in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, entity, roles

Let's say that in my system there are a few user roles: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_MODERATOR, ROLE_CUSTOMER_PERSON, ROLE_CUSOMER_COMPANY

And in the registration form I want to let the user choose what role he wants to have (between ROLE_CUSTOMER_PERSON and ROLE_CUSOMER_COMPANY).

So I added a `choice` type field into my form class with values 1 and 2. I can add a constraint which checks if a malicious user didn't choose any other one, that's ok. But now I have to somehow translate these 1 and 2 to ROLE_CUSTOMER_PERSON and ROLE_CUSOMER_COMPANY and use the addRole method to assign them or the isValid form function will fail on the $roles array property.

So is there a method that let's me "translate" things after first validation (if it's 1 or 2) and the form's isValid method automatically?

I know I could just use the Request object, validate it manually and then set it in the entity and THEN validate the rest of the form but it's just nasty and I would have to do that every single time I want to use the form.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add a custom form type, smtg like RoleType?

You can see how to do this in the [documentation here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html)

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you pass the values directly in the choice field ?

```
$builder->add('role', 'choice', ['choices' => [ 'ROLE_CUSTOMER_PERSON' ] ]);
```

when form binds, it will call this method on data object:

```
$user->setRole('ROLE_CUSTOMER_PERSON'); // or addRole
```

You could also imagine that the `addRole` method is smart enough to transform the 1 and 2 values into correct strings.

Comment: I did just like you said and setRole is not even called (var_dump('sssss')) is not displayed (in other methods it is)

Comment: can you paste your Form config ? (the Type class, or whatever you use)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [DataTransformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html).

Otherwise you could use a [listener/subscriber](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Form/FormEvents.html) to convert your form data when one of symfony's [form events](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Form/FormEvents.html) occurs.